# Why won't this script work when calling variables

Tags: bash, shell, syntax

SO here's my full script.  As you can see below the script works fine with compiling when variables are not entered into the export.
Once I add variables into the export it will not compile due to something.  IF I echo the variable MET_PYTHON_CC & MET_PYTHON_LD they are exactly the same if the variables are included or not.  Any ideas?

```
#!/bin/bash
export HOME=`cd;pwd`

#Basic Package Management for Model Evaluation Tools (MET)


sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install python3 python3-dev emacs flex bison libpixman-1-dev libjpeg-dev pkg-config libpng-dev unzip python2 python2-dev python3-pip pipenv gcc gfortran g++ libtool automake autoconf make m4 default-jre default-jdk csh ksh git ncview ncl-ncarg libncurses5 libncurses6 mlocate 


#Downloading latest dateutil due to python3.8 running old version.
pip3 install python-dateutil==2.8

#Directory Listings
mkdir $HOME/WRF
mkdir $HOME/WRF/MET-10.1.2
mkdir $HOME/WRF/MET-10.1.2/Downloads
mkdir $HOME/WRF/METplus-4.1.2
mkdir $HOME/WRF/METplus-4.1.2/Downloads



#Downloading MET and untarring files
#Note weblinks change often update as needed.
cd $HOME/WRF/MET-10.1.2/Downloads
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dtcenter/MET/main_v10.1/scripts/installation/compile_MET_all.sh

wget https://dtcenter.ucar.edu/dfiles/code/METplus/MET/installation/tar_files.tgz
wget https://github.com/dtcenter/MET/releases/download/v10.1.2/met-10.1.2.20220516.tar.gz

cp compile_MET_all.sh $HOME/WRF/MET-10.1.2
tar -xvzf tar_files.tgz -C $HOME/WRF/MET-10.1.2
cp met-10.1.2.20220516.tar.gz $HOME/WRF/MET-10.1.2/tar_files
cd $HOME/WRF/MET-10.1.2



# Installation of Model Evaluation Tools


cd $HOME/WRF/MET-10.1.2

sed -i 's/-fno-second-underscore -fallow-argument-mismatch/-fno-second-underscore -Wno-argument-mismatch/g' compile_MET_all.sh

################### This doesn't work 
export PYTHON_VERSION=$(/usr/bin/python3 -V 2>&1|awk '{print $2}')
export PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR_VERSION=$(echo $PYTHON_VERSION | awk -F. '{print $1}')
export PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR_VERSION=$(echo $PYTHON_VERSION | awk -F. '{print $2}')
export PYTHON_VERSION_COMBINED=$PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR_VERSION.$PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR_VERSION


export FC=/usr/bin/gfortran
export F77=/usr/bin/gfortran
export F90=/usr/bin/gfortran
export gcc_version=$(gcc -dumpfullversion)
export TEST_BASE=$HOME/WRF/MET-10.1.2
export COMPILER=gnu_$gcc_version
export MET_SUBDIR=${TEST_BASE}
export MET_TARBALL=met-10.1.2.20220516.tar.gz
export USE_MODULES=FALSE
export MET_PYTHON=/usr
export MET_PYTHON_CC=-I${MET_PYTHON}/include/python${PYTHON_VERSION_COMBINED}
export MET_PYTHON_LD=-L${MET_PYTHON}/lib/python${PYTHON_VERSION_COMBINED}/config-${PYTHON_VERSION_COMBINED}-x86_64-linux-gnu\ -L${MET_PYTHON}/lib\ -lpython${PYTHON_VERSION_COMBINED}\ -lcrypt\ -lpthread\ -ldl\ -lutil\ -lm
export SET_D64BIT=FALSE 

chmod 775 compile_MET_all.sh
./compile_MET_all.sh 
 
export PATH=$HOME/WRF/MET-10.1.2/bin:$PATH            #Add MET executables to path

cd 
$HOME/WRF-4.4-install-script-linux-64bit/METplus_self_install_script_Linux_64bit.sh

############# This works fine
export FC=/usr/bin/gfortran
export F77=/usr/bin/gfortran
export F90=/usr/bin/gfortran
export gcc_version=$(gcc -dumpfullversion)
export TEST_BASE=$HOME/WRF/MET-10.1.2                       
export COMPILER=gnu_$gcc_version                 
export MET_SUBDIR=${TEST_BASE}                   
export MET_TARBALL=met-10.1.2.20220516.tar.gz    
export USE_MODULES=FALSE                          
export MET_PYTHON=/usr                  
export MET_PYTHON_CC=-I${MET_PYTHON}/include/python3.10  
export MET_PYTHON_LD=-L${MET_PYTHON}/lib/python3.10/config-3.10-x86_64-linux-gnu\ -L${MET_PYTHON}/lib\ -lpython3.10\ -lcrypt\ -lpthread\ -ldl\ -lutil\ -lm   
export SET_D64BIT=FALSE  


chmod 775 compile_MET_all.sh
./compile_MET_all.sh 

export PATH=$HOME/WRF/MET-10.1.2/bin:$PATH            #Add MET executables to path

cd 
$HOME/WRF-4.4-install-script-linux-64bit/METplus_self_install_script_Linux_64bit.sh
```

Comment: If you run your code through https://www.shellcheck.net/ it suggests quoting your variables, i.e. try changing every `${variable}` to `"${variable}"`. It also suggests you declare and assign your variables in seperate processes to avoid unforeseen issues ("(warning): Declare and assign separately to avoid masking return values."). If you make these changes, do you still have the same problem?

Comment: @jared_mamrot yep still gives the issues.  I'm going to try to put double quotes around the first exports and see what happens.  Not exactly sure what double quotes do but at this point i'm guessing.

Comment: What's the output of `declare -p PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR_VERSION`?

Comment: add `set -x` and check the values

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano where?

Comment: @chepner

`will@will-XPS-8940:~/WRF/MET-10.1.2$ export PYTHON_VERSION="$(/usr/bin/python3 -V 2>&1|awk '{print $2}')"

export PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR_VERSION="$(echo $PYTHON_VERSION | awk -F. '{print $1}')"

export PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR_VERSION="$(echo $PYTHON_VERSION | awk -F. '{print $2}')"

echo $PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR_VERSION
echo $PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR_VERSION

3

10`

Comment: That's not what I asked for. I'm looking for evidence of carriage returns in the values.

Comment: @chepner

`declare -x PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR_VERSION="3"`


Think that is what you are asking for.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific about what "it doesn't work" means, then. Do you get any error messages? The code you are showing now doesn't "do" anything; it just sets some environment variable values.

Comment: @chepner : Well, the code **does** at least invoke `compile_MET_all.sh`, and I guess that this is where the environment variables are used, and probably it is there where a closer investigation could be helpful. Of course the subsequent setting of the PATH and the `cd` (i.e. after running compile_MET_all.sh) are non-sense, unless the whole script has been sourced. Unfortuately the OP is not showing how the script is actually invoked.

Comment: Share us the error log